# Let $f_\alpha,g_\alpha:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $\max_\alpha f_\alpha - \max_\alpha g_\alpha \le \max_\alpha (f_\alpha-g_\alpha)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f_\alpha,g_\alpha:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Under which hypothesis do we have that $$\max_\alpha f_\alpha - \max_\alpha g_\alpha \le \max_\alpha (f_\alpha-g_\alpha)$$ holds?

Comment: What is $ a {}$?

Comment: @DHMO A parameter in the expression of $f,g$.

Comment: Can you prove that $\sup_{\alpha} (f_{\alpha}+g_{\alpha}) \leq \sup_{\alpha} f_{\alpha} + \sup_{\alpha} g_{\alpha}$? What happens if we apply this inequality to $(f_\alpha - g_\alpha, g_\alpha)$ in place of $(f_\alpha, g_\alpha)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I assume from your problem that all three of those maximum values that you mention in task exist.

Notice, that $f(x) - g(x) \geq f(x) - \max_x g(x)$, because for any $x$ we have that $g(x)\leq \max_x g(x)$. Let $C = \max_x g(x)$. Using the fact that if $a(x) \geq b(x)$ for any $x$, then $\max_x a(x) \geq \max_x b(x)$ we have that

$$\max_x (f(x)-g(x)) \geq \max_x (f(x) - C) = \max_x f(x)- C = \max_x f(x) - \max_x g(x).$$